# Static HTML page in Flask while redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Flask app that takes in a url, does some logic and redirects the user to another url.  I'd like to just generate a static html page that basically says "please wait" while the logic is executing. 
Is there a nice way to do asynchronous stuff like this in jQuery?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/stuff/morestuff/')
def stuff():
    #can I load html here without a return()?

    #request.args input url, calls out to api, generates new url
    return redirect(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. When an HTTP request is made to your server, the server gets to send back one response. That can be a success, a redirect, or several other types of responses. There is rarely a reason to do what you're describing because responding with a redirect is typically a fast operation.

However, if you really want to achieve that sort of behavior, you would need to respond with a success and have the page with which you respond take care of handling the redirect using javascript. At this point, you could perform all the logic client-side using JS, or use AJAX/websockets to communicate with the server for additional information while the user is told to wait. Keep in mind this method requires the user to have JavaScript enabled, which should not be necessary for a simple redirect.